# How to Change state of one component to another component in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, navbar

I am new to react, and i need to send the image to Navbar component. For example, I have Component called A, and imagine NavBar as Component B, but i have not used NavBar component directly into my Component A, instead i am calling it from index.js

Comment: You should read the document first, there you can get better idea about state management and other useful information: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html, https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state

Answer (score 0):

It depends mostly on the way how do you get this image.
If you're getting this image from API and this image needs to use in both children of App, just get this image in App.js and then pass as a prop to children.

If it's a static asset, the best choice is to import image in both components.
How to do it with CRA: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files

Comment: you want to load image one time and access in multiple components? kindly update your question with tags. right now I can understand that in which domain you are asking questions. thanks

Comment: @Vladyslav Yefimenko  - getting images from API call and still using these API call in both the components, my problem is not updating the image immediatly after refresh its getting update. i want without refresh or reload the page.

Comment: @Vicky What do you mean by refresh? I guess you're doing something wrong if API call is triggering a page reload.
I propose you make one API call from the App (parent component) and then pass the image as a prop to both children of App.

A couple of questions to understand the context better:
1. Do you use react-router?
2. How do you do API calls? Maybe Axios?
3. How did you set up your project? Create React App?